# Pinia | Vue3 - Accessing array in deep object

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, pinia

In Pinia (base.js)

```js
export const useBaseStore = defineStore('base', {
  state: () => {
    return {
      areaLocal: [
        { id: 0, name: 'LAX' },
        { id: 1, name: 'SFO' },
        { id: 2, name: 'SAN' },
      ],
      areaLocal2: {
        area: [
          { id: 0, name: 'AAA' },
          { id: 1, name: 'BBB' },
          { id: 2, name: 'CCC' },
        ]
      },
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getAreaById: (state) => {
      return (areaId) =>
        state.areaLocal.find((areaLocal) => areaLocal.id === areaId)
    },
    // ...
  }
})
```

in Vue (area.vue)

```
<script setup>
import { computed, ref } from 'vue'
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
import { useBaseStore } from '../stores/base'

const areaStore = useBaseStore()
const { getAreaById } = storeToRefs(areaStore)
const areaIndex = ref(0)
</script>
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>AREA: {{ getAreaById(areaIndex).name }}</h2>
....
```

This, `areaLocal`, I get "AREA: LAX", which is correct,
but HOW I can write "getter" in the pinia for access to "areaLocal2", the object "area" then the array?

```
state.areaLocal2.area.find((areaLocal2.area) => areaLocal.id.area === areaId
```

The above throws an `undefined` error.

Comment: `it doesn't work` ... what error do you see?

Comment: Thank you Jaromada X, I got "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target (at base.js?t=1657670760135:35:45)" .... `find((areaLoca2.are) => ` this doesn't work, maybe...

Comment: `x.y` is not a valid argument name for a function - see the answer - it doesn't explain what you did wrong, but it shows what to do right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getArea2ById: (state) => (areaIa) => state.areaLocal2.area.find((area) => area.id === areaId)
```

You are already in `area` by the time you hit the `find` higher order function so no need to reference it again inside of it.

Comment: Thank you Riza, however I got an error "area.vue:40 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')"....`<h2>AREA: {{ getArea2ById(areaIndex).name }}</h2>`

Comment: try this: `{{ getArea2ById(areaIndex)?.name }}`

Comment: The error isn't related to the getter. You are trying to reference a property which (by the time the browser reads the file) doesn't exist.

Comment: FANTASTIC!!! Thank you million Riza. "?" works!

Comment: Optional Chaining if you want to read more about it. In Vue3, it will be very useful to familiarize yourself with it

Comment: "Optional chaining
The optional chaining ?. stops the evaluation if the value before ?. is undefined or null and returns undefined. "  -- Very interesting. Still A LOT TO Learn, Thank you Riza again